# Load the content of a given URL in yui 3.2 using AJAX

Tags: ajax, yui, yui3

```
Y.one('#message').load('/ajax/test.html');
Y.one('#message').load('/ajax/test.html', '#foo');
```

Load the content of a given URL and replace the contents of #message with it.

In YUI, the node-load module provides this functionality. YUI also optionally supports extracting only a portion of the loaded content if a selector string is passed as the second argument (assuming the content is HTML).

This is possible in yui3.3.
Is this also possible in yui 3.2 also? because I want to implement same thing in yui 3.2 only? or Is there any other workaround for this if its not possible in yui 3.2?

Please share your ideas. Any help would be appreciated.